# DOMDocument::createElementNS for URL with multiple parameters

Tags: php, saml, suitecrm

This DOMDocument::createElementNS is being used by [lightSAML](https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML) package, but it ends up breaking when the `namespaceURI` has multiple parameters in it.

The URL

`https://suitecrm_dev.com/index.php?action=Login&module=Users`

It only works for URL

`https://mautic_dev.com/s/saml/login_check`

in the official document for [createElementNS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php) the example provided is a URL that doesn't have a parameter in it.

So the question here is how can I send the URL properly so that DOMDocument::createElementNS doesn't give me this error:

**DOMDocument::createElementNS(): unterminated entity reference module=Users**

Line in lightSAML causing the problem: https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML/blob/377f04d1fb25f2fb2e72dabeff10b336f1cbe4c5/src/LightSaml/Model/AbstractSamlModel.php#L108

And yes I already asked a question in LightSAML and SuiteCRM but to no avail, I also posted a question here but decided to make a new one that points you to the line causing all these problems.

Comment: According to the error message, it thinks `&module` was supposed the name of an entity, but doesn’t find the terminating `;` those require. Try and encode the `&` as `&amp;`.

Comment: @CBroe aye, that did remove the error but the SSO still fails though I think it's because of the URI but that's a different topic.

Comment: @CBroe that help me solved it, had to do a lot of digging to find what functions were using that URL and to update them accordingly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[XML namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#iri-use) are `URI`s not `URL`s.

```
https://suitecrm_dev.com/index.php?action=Login&module=Users
```

is a `URL`. It locates a resource whereas:

```
https://mautic_dev.com/s/saml/login_check
```

is a `URI` as it identifies a resource. The physical location of the resource could be anywhere, even a completely different domain in a `URL`.

`SAML` core only deals with identities. `SAML` metadata deals with locations of identities. Although it's possible to encode the parameters into the URI this is discouraged:

> Because of the risk of confusion between URIs that would be equivalent
> if dereferenced, the use of %-escaped characters in namespace names is
> strongly discouraged.

So it's best to consider which entity (identity) the `DOMDocument::createElementNS` represents rather than where the information will end up (location).

Comment: I get you but the problem is SuiteCRM didn't specify any URI for SAML, and most of the docs I've read is using `https://suitecrm_dev.com/index.php?action=Login&module=Users` which in itself is strange since that's the login page.

Comment: which SAML element are you adding the namespace to?

Comment: the destination you can see it here in the building the response. https://imbringingsyntaxback.com/implementing-a-saml-idp-with-laravel/

Comment: is it the namespace or the Destination attribute value you're having problems with?

Comment: it's both in a sense since the destination URL you find in the link is also the namespaceURI used in the lightsaml function. But I managed to solve this problem now by encoding the URL and just doing some str_replace to make the URL work when it's used for the destination link. it's not a pretty solution.